# Best way to structure deployment script?

Tags: powershell, relative-path

I have a PowerShell script to deploy some database code. It is a SSDT project and it is structured thus:

```
Root
    \Deployment
        \Scripts
            Deploy.ps1
        \Config
            deploy.config
    \SolutionRoot
        \DatabaseProject
        \UnitTestProject
```

To do a test deployment on my workstation I change to `\Deployment\Scripts` and run `Deploy.ps1` and it works fine. When I run it from my Jenkins build server, the current working directory is the root folder (not scripts). So the `Deploy.ps1` scripts fails to run when invoked like: `powershell -File Deployment\Scripts\Deploy.ps1`

For example I have this code near the top of the script as debug:

```
$currentDirectory = (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName
Write-Host "Current Working Directory: $currentDirectory"
```

and when run on my workstation it returns:

`Current Working Directory: C:\repos\MyRoot\Deployment\Scripts`

when run on the build server it returns

`Current Working Directory: D:\Jenkins\workspace\MyRootWithADifferentName`

I would like the script to run no matter where it is, so what's the best way to know whereabouts in the directory structure I am? Build servers may vary and the name of the Root directory may vary too, but all the others are static relative to Root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this do termine the path of the current script:

```
$currentDirectory = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```